# Edit a Rails scaffold class to add a new field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scaffolding

I've generated a simple Rails 3 class using the scaffold function:

```
rails generate scaffold Fattura data:date importo:integer descrizione:text
```

Now I need to add another field in the class `Fattura`. What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a migration which adds a column:

```
rails generate migration add_my_column_to_fattura my_column:string
rake db:migrate
```

Comment: How is this specifying which table to add my_column to?

Comment: The table name is inferred from the model name, which in turn is inferred from the last part of the migration name (the part after the `to`).